# Google checkout subscription solution

Tags: asp.net, google-checkout

I configured Google checkout subscription for my asp.net website.
But I have some problems with it.

1. How can I cancel subscription payment?
2. How can I test subscription payment with sandbox environment?

*(I mean if I setup weekly subscription whether it will send payment notifications in sandbox environment)*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution, It will be helpful for someone

```
CancelItemsRequest cma = new CancelItemsRequest(System.Web.Configuration.WebConfigurationManager.AppSettings["GoogleMerchantID"].ToString(), System.Web.Configuration.WebConfigurationManager.AppSettings["GoogleMerchantKey"].ToString(), EnvironmentType.Sandbox.ToString(), ["merchant_invoice_id"], "Message", "");
                cma.AddMerchantItemId("2"); // item id to cancel
                cma.MerchantID = System.Web.Configuration.WebConfigurationManager.AppSettings["GoogleMerchantID"].ToString();
                cma.MerchantKey = System.Web.Configuration.WebConfigurationManager.AppSettings["GoogleMerchantKey"].ToString();
                cma.Environment = EnvironmentType.Sandbox;
                cma.SendEmail = false;
                GCheckoutResponse Respa = cma.Send();
```